# WPF Force UserControl to expand to fill maximal render size

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, layout, contentcontrol

I need to create a UserControl, which is hosted within a "parent" ContentControl who is set with "Center" Horizontal and Vertical alignment.

This control hosts another "child" UserControl, which I would like to be as big as it can get without stretching over the render-able size.

I noticed that if I set the child's size to be bigger than the render-able size, i get the size I want as a "DesiredSize" property on that control.
However I don't see how can I get that information without oversizing the control.

I've created this sample to illustrate the situation, I want "ChildControl"'s pink background to stretch over the entire window.

Just to clarify, I only have control on "ControlableElementA" and "ControlableElementB"
I cannot bind to the main window, in the actual application I use this as an embedded window with varying levels of hierarchy in between..

The "ChildControl" and "ParentControl" are beyond my reach due to constraints above me.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Name="ParentControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Name="ControlableElementA" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ContentControl Name="ControlableElementB">
                    <Grid Name="ChildControl" Background="Pink" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks ahead, I apologize if the description is a little cryptic

Comment: You could try changing ChildControl to be a DockPanel, and set the LastChildFill property to true.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned In the real application, do not have any power over the contents of the childControl.
Thanks for the response in any case.

Answer (score 3):

`HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` as `Stretch` means *"Stretch to the maximum size within the bounds of the parent container."*

However, your parent container is set to `Center`, which means your `UserControl` effectively has an `Auto` width and height.

To fix this, simply remove:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

From the `ContentControl`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the parent control. otherwise the solution would be trivial..
I made this sample to abstractly display a much more complex architecture.

Thanks for the response in any case.